# mejorar codigo, promise and Map

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Hola tengo un codigo funcional pero no me arroja el resultado como lo espero, hago una busqueda con unas condiciones en el query y funciona pero el resultado me lo trae como varios arreglos json y lo que quiero es un solo arreglo json, aca el codgio a ver si alguien puede ver la falla:

```
  var comparaPago = (lista) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var listaPagos = Pagos.find({
                "user_id": lista.user,
                "fecha_pago": {
                    "$lt": lista.createdAt
                }
            }, (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
                if (!err) {

                    return registrosEncontrados

                }
            }
            ).sort({ fecha_pago: -1 })
                .limit(1)
            resolve(listaPagos);

        });
```

y aqui llamo a la promesa que itera una respuesta de un proceso anterior:

```
   ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response => {
        if (response !== null) {

            var miLista = Promise.all(
                response.map(elemento => {
                    return comparaPago(elemento);
                }));
        }

        miLista
            .then(lista => {
                return res.status(200).json(lista)

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })

}
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

```
  [],
    [],
    [
        {
            "_id": "59fc6f6aaf24f50ea619ac97",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-03T13:40:36.980Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-11-03T13:30:18.729Z",
            "user_id": "563857ed3817661751605eaf",

        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "_id": "59a01d948642d70e294f6fd0",
            "updatedAt": "2017-08-25T13:00:34.622Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-08-25T12:52:36.934Z",
            "user_id": "563855fe38176617515fa8ae"
}

    ]
```

lo que quisiera seria un solo arreglo, y sin los vacios, pero no se en que fallo, algo asi:

```
[        {
            "_id": "59a01d948642d70e294f6fd0",
            "updatedAt": "2017-08-25T13:00:34.622Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-08-25T12:52:36.934Z",
            "user_id": "563855fe38176617515fa8ae"
}, 
 {
            "_id": "59fc6f6aaf24f50ea619ac97",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-03T13:40:36.980Z",
            "createdAt": "2017-11-03T13:30:18.729Z",
            "user_id": "563857ed3817661751605eaf",

        }

]
```

gracias y disculpen los errores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas conceptualmente mal implementadas.

1. Valor de retorno del método `find`
   El método `find` de un *Schema* devuelve un *thenable*, por lo que tu función `comparaPago` realmente es una `Promise` que resuelve en un *thenable*, no el resultado de la llamada a la base de datos

```
const comparaPago = lista =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Pagos.find({
            "user_id": lista.user,
            "fecha_pago": {
                "$lt": lista.createdAt
            }
        }, (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
            // En caso de error, rechazamos la Promise
            // En caso contrario, la resolvemos.
            err ? reject(err)
                : resolve(registrosEncontrados);
        }).sort({ fecha_pago: -1 })
          .limit(1);
    });
```

2. El *guard* en el `then` de `ListarUsuariosMaxDate`
   Haces el `if` para ver si `response` es nulo o no e inicializas `miLista` en ese *scope*, pero lo usas fuera.
   `miLista` es una `Promise` que va a resolver un *array* con todos los resultados. Un resultado (potencialmente) por elemento en `response`.

```
ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response => {
    // Sacamos provecho de la js type coercion
    // para comparar tanto con null como con undefined
    if (response) {
        const promise = Promise.all(response.map(comparaPago));
        promise.then(listOfResults => {
            // En este punto tenemos
            // La lista con los resultados.
            // Un return aquí no tiene efecto,
            // porque la cadena de then no sigue...
        });
        // No pongo el catch para que escale en el catch de
        // ListarUsuariosMaxDate
    }
}).catch(console.error);
```

3. `find` va a resolver con un *array* de datos
   Aunque especifiques el `limit(1)`, `find` siempre resolverá un *array*. En este caso, un *array* de un elemento (si encuentra datos en la *query*) o un *array* vacío, si no los encuentra.
   Por ello, podemos hacer un [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flat) del *array* para obtener los datos en un solo *array* sin anidados.

```
// Aplica el flat a un solo nivel
const flatArray = arr => arr.flat(1);

ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response => {
    if (response) {
        const promise = Promise.all(response.map(comparaPago));
        promise.then(flatArray)
               .then(listOfResults => {
                    // listOfResults ya es el array sin arrays anidados
               });
    }
}).catch(console.error);
```

Espero que sirva.